SQL Server using Powershell - Error: the 'Invoke-SqlCmd' command was found in the module 'SQLPS', but the module could not be loaded
I'm encountering an error when trying to create a database and also to execute other queries in SQL Server using PowerShell's Invoke-SqlCmd command.
Environment:

Windows Version: 10.0.19045
PowerShell Version: 5.1.19041.4780

Powershell command used:
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "localhost\sqlexpress" 
              -Query "CREATE DATABASE dummy_db"

Error:

Invoke-SqlCmd : The 'Invoke-SqlCmd' command was found in the module 'SQLPS', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module SQLPS'.
At line:1 char:1


Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "localhost\sqlexpress" -Query "CREATE D ...



CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-SqlCmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule


Outside Powershell:

I can successfully execute queries directly from the command prompt using sqlcmd.
I can also manage the database using third-party tools like HeidiSQL with no issues.
I attempted to troubleshoot using a similar Stack Overflow thread (URL: Powershell Invoke-SQLCmd and SQLPS) but haven't found a solution.

What additional troubleshooting steps can I take to resolve this error? Is there any step I missed?

So what happened when you followed the error's instructions? What about that information didn't you understand? What was that information?

I have followed the directions from a similar thread, by installing the sqlserver module in powershell, it says it is already there. Command: Install-module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser. Result: PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this system:'Add-SqlAvailabilityDat
abase,Add-SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp, etc

But what about the instructions in the error...? You haven't told us what happened when you followed the error's instructions. It might seem like a "silly" question but; have you read the error message? What about the error didn't you understand and the instructions it gave you?

And also check for the existence of sqlps using command: Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Sqlps.
ModuleType Version    Name
Manifest   15.0       SQLPS

When importing module, Import-Module SQLPS, I got error: Import-Module : File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\Sqlps\SqlPsPostScript.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Ok, so have you read that link? What about that link didn't you understand..?

Oh I see. Here's the culprit: because running scripts is disabled on this system. I will find out more.

Thanks Thom for directing me. Previously, because I always got a lot of red error messages, I missed that section.

Please do read your error messages before posting on [so]; this site is for when you and tried and failed to solve the problem, not to post your question when you hit the first bump in road. If the error gives you instructions, follow them; they are informative for a reason.

OK, Tom. I'll be more careful next time. Should I delete this question or leave it as is?

As explained in the comments, this error occurs because the PowerShell execution policy is set to a restricted mode, preventing the execution of scripts. So I tried changing the execution policy with the command: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser, and finally the Invoke-SqlCmd command could be executed successfully.
Thanks
DeeKey

It would be helpful if the error message from SQLPS were more helpful. Have you tried getting current on PowerShell Core 7 and the SqlServer module instead of SQLPS?

Hi lit, I haven't tried it yet, maybe later if I want to dig deeper. But thanks for the insight.
